# Scene couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 9 levels in my games but when I run the game Unity keep increasing my scene index and said the error scene couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings. Here is the current error. It said scene 33 couldn't be loaded but I have only 9. Please help me how to fix this.Thank you

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7uI.png)

Here is my code for levels.I just increase 1 levels every time the player finish:

```
IEnumerator NextLevel()
{
    finish = true;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", 1) + 1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"));
}
```

Comment: The error message sounds quite self-explanatory ... add the scenes to your [build settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) ... and well where does the 33 come from? Seems that you already tried a bunch of times and after reaching `10` always get that error but still increase the level index ;) .. you should implement something to clamp it to a maximum index ;)

Comment: No I have added it to my build setting but I have only 9 levels and the error said couldnt load scene 31. It keep increase scene every time I click play.

Comment: well yes that is what you code does .. save a higher value to the player prefs then try to load that scene ... as said ... make sure it is maxed at your highest level inex

Comment: if you have only 9 scenes, what exactly do you want it to do when you finish the last made level, lets say 8 because 0 is a menu.

Comment: @BugFinder I want to return to scene 1 to start the game again can you tell me how to reset the count.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the index to load is clamped to the actual levels available!

```
privte const int maxLevel = 9;

IEnumerator NextLevel()
{
    finish = true;
    var currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", 1);
    var nextLevel = currentLevel + 1;
    if(nextLevel > maxLevel)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(No more levels available);
        yield break;
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", nextLevel);
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(Level + nextLevel.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I tried it but now it appear "No more level available". It is a way to erase the memory of unity load scenes. I think it still remeber loading scene 33.

Comment: reset your player prefs .. either via code `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Level");` or directly in the registry

Comment: Thank you I got it. But it seems like my code increased 2 levels instead of 1. Like level 1 to level 3 to level 5. Can you tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you need to reset your PlayerPrefs after reading answer and all comments. @derHugo already answered how to delete a Key from PlayerPrefs. Additionally I want to add something -

You can now delete all keys in PlayerPrefs by simply `Edit > Clear All PlayerPrefs` doing it.

Or, [Use this tool](https://github.com/sabresaurus/PlayerPrefsEditor) to delete a specific key from the editor.

Comment: Thank you I got it. But it seems like my code increased 2 levels instead of 1. Like level 1 to level 3 to level 5. Can you tell me how to fix it.